# What is the Name of System Settings for terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, settings

What can I type to launch system settings from the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
gnome-control-center
```

Comment: yes thats it not sure why I didn't try that I saw it but never tried it

Comment: @Core: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.